# Batch Process - Could not deserialize object

Tags: mule, deserialization, mule-studio, batching

I've been playing around with the Batch processor recently, and in testing it's been working fine.

I have since added it to our main project flow and I'm getting a strange issue.

The Batch process itself contains nothing but a Logger, and the payload sent to it is a LineIterator.

The problem I'm having is it's throwing a SerializationException. The odd thing is the first time it's run it throws that exception at run time. After that it won't compile, throwing the same exception.

Here's the batch process from the flow and the pertinent stack info when failing to build.The full trace is attached to this post on the Mule forum: https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/65671/batch-process-could-not-deserialize-object.html

```
 <batch:job name="revenue-batch-Flow" block-size="10">
 <batch:process-records>
     <batch:step name="Batch_Step" accept-expression="#[!org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank( payload )]">
         <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     </batch:step>
 </batch:process-records>
</batch:job>

 Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 Serialization trace:
 value (org.mule.transformer.types.TypedValue)
 properties (org.mule.session.DefaultMuleSession)
 session (org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent)
 muleEvent (com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchJobInstance)
```

Any ideas on what's causing this strange behaviour?

**UPDATE**

Just to add a bit of context. I'm attempting to iterate over the lines in a file that has been read from SFTP.

This endpoint itself is created mid-flow in a Java component:

```
    @Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext muleEventContext) throws Exception {

    String sftpUri = muleEventContext.getMessage().getProperty( "sesSftpUri", PropertyScope.SESSION);

    EndpointBuilder endpointBuilder = muleEventContext.getMuleContext().getEndpointFactory().getEndpointBuilder( sftpUri );
    endpointBuilder.addMessageProcessor(new MessageFilter(new FilenameWildcardFilter(muleEventContext.getMessage().getProperty( "sesFileName", PropertyScope.SESSION)) ));

    InboundEndpoint inboundEndpoint = endpointBuilder.buildInboundEndpoint();

    MuleMessage muleMessage = inboundEndpoint.request(30000L);

    return muleMessage;
}
```

I've just checked and I can batch on the same file locally, so it's an issue with this endpoint or its configuration. Can I configure this endpoint to put the file in a temp directory and read it from there?

Comment: Added an update, the problem seems to be related to the endpoint created mid-flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out the issue in the end.

We were using a session variable of an Immutable Map type, and although not used anywhere around the batch process, was causing the above error.

After removing this variable as part of the batch Input stage there were no further issues.

Answer (score 1):

The batch job splits the original payload (must be Collection or Iterator) serializes the splitted messages (including payload) into its persistent batch queue.

Is your message payload (after split) serializable?

Another problem is the persistence: Try to check "Clear Application Data" in the run configuration. When that does not help, delete the directory /mule/.mule/.mule/ in your workspace.

You probably know the batch job documentation:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/batch-processing

Comment: Hi Roger, the LineIterator should be returning Strings, which I was able to batch on previously. I tried as you suggested to Clear Application Data and delete the /.mule directory but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried in debugger? What if you replace the batch with a collection spliiter or a for each loop?

Comment: Hi Roger, I've updated my original post with more detail. I need to look into if it's the way I'm instantiating the endpoint myself that's causing this issue to appear. I've been pulled onto another task at work, when I get a chance to re-visit this flow I'll update with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

In anypoint Studio Mule -> "Clear Application Data" worked for me as @rbutenuth said